# Find the document with null value in it

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have multiple documents, and some of them contain `null` as value for key `IP`.

eg:

```
{
    "_id":ObjectId("id"),
    "nodename":"first"
},
{
    "_id":ObjectId("id"),
    "nodename":"second",
    IP:null
},
{
    "_id":ObjectId("id"),
    "nodename":"third",
    IP:"192.168.0.5"
}
```

when I try to fetch those with the query:

```
db.collection.find({"IP":null})
```

it returns all the documents which either has `null` value or the documents with no IP field.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$type` 10

```
db.collection.find({"IP": {$type: 10}});
```

Documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/#type-check

> The {"IP": {$type: 10}} query matches only documents that contain the item field whose value is null; i.e. the value of the item field is of BSON Type Null (type number 10)

Answer (score 3):

Another option is this query:

```
db.inventory.find({$and: [ {IP: { $exists: true }}, {IP: {$eq: null}} ]})
```

It seems to me more obvious than type checking.